# How can I addition mysql numeric data with another mysql numeric data

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
        $new_result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT input_cost FROM data_input");
        while ($new = mysqli_fetch_array($new_result)) {

            $sum += $new['input_cost'];
        }

        echo "<h2> total cost of this month is $".$sum. "</h2>";

     ?>
```

but the result say

```
<br>
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: sum in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\work_shop\back_end\data_input_output\result.php on
>   line 57

```
<br>
```

total cost of this month is `$300`
which is correct result....

```
<br>
```

How can I solve this problem...??

Comment: define  `$sum` before loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `$sum` variable outside loop. Try this-

```
<?php 


$sum = 0; // define sum outside loop

$new_result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT input_cost FROM data_input");
while ($new = mysqli_fetch_array($new_result)) {

     $sum += $new['input_cost'];
}

 echo "<h2> total cost of this month is $".$sum. "</h2>";

?>
```

Answer (score 3):

$sum is undefined because you are only adding, and not setting a value.

```
<?php 
  $new_result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT input_cost FROM data_input");
  $sum = 0;
  while ($new = mysqli_fetch_array($new_result)) {
    $sum += $new['input_cost'];
  }
  echo '<h2> total cost of this month is $'.$sum.'</h2>';
?>
```